# Delete elements in vector by position?

Tags: c++, sdl, stdvector

In my class I am trying to remove an element from a `std::vector` using a `for` loop.  However, when I try to remove the element, I receive an error and I am not quite sure how to solve it. The error I get is:

> Error 4   error C2679: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Enemy *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
void Enemy::UpdateEnemies(SDL_Renderer * render)
{
    for (int i = enemies.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        enemies[i]->Update();
        if (enemies[i]->Active == false)
        {
            // Receive the error here
            enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + enemies.at(i));             
        }
    }
    if ((SDL_GetTicks()-prevSpawnTime)/1000.0f > enemySpawnTime)
    {
        prevSpawnTime = SDL_GetTicks();
        //Add an anemy
        AddEnemy(render);
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + i);`

Comment: @DimChtz Lol never mind. I had tried that before and the reason it wasn't working is because i declared the active variable but never initialized it. my bad but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have given you the naive solution.  However, if you have more than one enemy to remove, you need a better solution.

Using `std::remove_if` from `<algorithm>` would be better in this case.  That will avoid repeated shuffling of the items in your vector.  It works by moving all the ones you want to remove to the *end* of the container, and then giving you an iterator to the beginning of those.

```
auto removed_iter = std::remove_if( enemies.begin(), enemies.end(),
                                    []( const Enemy * e ) { return e->IsActive(); } );

enemies.erase( removed_iter, enemies.end() );
```

In this case you would have to update all your enemies first.  If that doesn't need to be done in reverse order, then:

```
for( auto e : enemies ) e->Update();
```

Comment: Note that this code is for C++11 onwards.  Shouldn't really have to state that these days, but some people are still using old compilers.  Also, the fact I'm passing `const Enemy *` mandates that you implemented `Enemy::IsActive` with const-correctness.  If you have compile errors, consider that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to remove the `i`-th element, you need to do

```
enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + i);
```

or better

```
enemies.erase(std::next(enemies.begin(), i));
```

In your case `enemies.at(i)` returns the dereferenced iterator at position `i`, i.e. an element of type `Enemy`, and not `i` or the iterator for position `i`.

A better way is to use reverse iterators:

```
for(auto it = enemies.rbegin(); it != enemies.rend(); ++it)
{
    (*it)->Update();
    if ((*it)->Active == false)
    {   // need `base()` to convert to regular iterator, then substract 1
        enemies.erase(std::prev(it.base())); // remove the current position
        /* or, equivalently
        enemies.erase(std::next(it).base()); 
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + enemies.at(i));
```

- enemise.at(i) returns the Enemy that is stored in the vector.
- enemies.begin() is a pointer

As the error says, you are trying to add pointer and vector.

You probably want just to call:

```
enemies.erase(enemies.begin() + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, I would take it a step further and suggest that erasing from a vector within a loop could cause undefined behavior.  I don't see a break, so I assume that there could be multiple inactive enemies.  Instead of writing your own loop, consider using the std::remove_if algorithm.  Essentially your code is an attempt to add an iterator with an object reference which will fail to compile.  The remove_if solution will essentially copy all enemies where Active==false to the end of the container while shifting everything else forward.  It provides a convenient way to first identify the things to remove, and then erase them all at once.  Additionally if you don't have a C++11 compiler the same thing will work if you use a different kind of predicate.  The remove_if link contains an example of a function, but you can also use a functor.

```
enemies.erase(std::remove_if(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), [](const Enemy* e){ return e->Active == false; }), enemies.end());
```

For more information check these out.

[What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

[C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)